# C++ map<string, vector<char> > access

Tags: c++, stl, vector, dictionary

I've created a map of vectors that looks like this:

```
map<string, vector<char> > myMap;
string key = "myKey";
vector<char> myVector;
myMap[key] = myVector;
```

I want to be able to append 'char's' to the vector in the map but I can't figure out how to access said vector to append once the particular key/value(vector) has been created. Any suggestions?  I'm iterating over char's and might be adding a lot to the vector as I go so it would be nice to have a simple way to do it.  Thanks.

---

I would like the vector in map to be appended as I go.  I don't need the original vector...I just need to return the map of key/vector's that I've created (after apending) so that I can pass it to another function.  What does the * in map* > do?  Is that refrencing a pointer?  (I haven't gotten there in lecture yet)  Also, do I     need: 
    myMap[key]->push_back('s');
or 
    myMap[key].push_back('s');
??

Comment: Are you trying to create a hash table?

Comment: To be clear -- do you want to append to `myVector`, or to the copy of that object which is stored in the map? Mir Milad Hosseiny has answered as if you want to use the map to append to `myVector`, so either that answer is applicable, or all the others are.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To append:

```
myMap[key].push_back('c');
```

Or use `myMap.find`, but then you have to check whether you get an `end` iterator. `operator[]` returns a reference to the `vector`.

But this modifies the `vector` stored in the `map`, not the original one, since you've stored a copy in the `map` with `myMap[key] = myVector;`. If that's not what you want, you should rethink your design and maybe store (smart) pointers to vectors in your map.

Comment: By doing this, a copy of vector is created and a pushed to cloned vector and original vector is empty.

Comment: @MirMiladHosseiny: ok, I now see what you mean, but I assumed the OP would be using the vectors stored in the map rather than the original one.

Comment: What the ....? Nonsense! `myMap[key]` is an lvalue to the `std::vector<char>` in the map. The expression `myMap[key].push_back('c');` is absolutely fine and the way to go! (+1 on the answer).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: well, the OP's question is a bit ambiguous. They want to "access said vector", but there are actually two vectors due to the copying.

Comment: @larsmans: This is what it says right after the code example: "I want to be able to append 'char's' to the vector in the map ..." To me, this doesn't leave a lot of ambiguity. Admittedly, I don't see what the original problem really is either way although give the fact that multiple answers lacked the use of a reference I have a vague suspicion.

Answer (score 6):

Given you know the key:

```
string key = "something";
char ch = 'a'; // the character you want to append

map<string, vector<char> >::iterator itr = myMap.find(key);
if(itr != myMap.end())
{
    vector<char> &v = itr->second;
    v.push_back(ch);
}
```

you could also use the `map::operator[]` to access the map entry, but if the key does not exist, a new entry with that key will be created:

```
vector<char> &v = myMap[key]; // a map entry will be created if key does not exist
v.push_back(ch);
```

or simply:

```
myMap[key].push_back(ch);
```

Comment: It must be `vector<char>& v`. So the `v.push_back(ch)` work on what iterator point to.

Comment: @Meysam: lionbest is correct: if you insist on referencing `iter->second` by another name (e.g. `v`) you need to, well, reference it: `std::vector<char>& v = iter->second;`.

Comment: @Meysam: even when using the subscript operator which may create new elements when they don't exist, you still need to use a reference: otherwise you append to a copy.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: You are right. I needed to use a reference. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To access the mapped value, which in your case is a vector, you just supply the key in square brackets like you did to assign the value.
So, to append 'a':

```
myMap[key].push_back('a');
```

Comment: By doing this, a copy of vector is created and `a` pushed to cloned vector and original vector is empty.

Comment: No. `myMap[key]` returns a reference, so it modify the vector inside the map.

Comment: @lionbest - the OP says he wants to "append 'char's' to the vector in the map", so I believe this is right.

Answer (score 0):

I have an new suggestion. You can use `vector<char>*` instead of `vector<char>` in order to collect pointer of vectors in your `map`. For more information see the bellow code:

```cpp
map<string, vector<char>* > myMap;
string key = "myKey";
vector<char>* myVector = new vector<char>();
myMap[key] = myVector;
myMap[key]->push_back('S');
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of using pointers to `std::vector<char>` beyond almost certainly creating a memory leak?